# How do I make a modular keyboard controller in Java?

Tags: java, oop, input, io, keyboard-events

I am currently building a game where I would need to do the following:

- New currentControls(defualt);
- User selects an object on the board
- If (selectedObj instanceof typeOfObj) { currentControls.setControls(typeOfObjControls); }

Is there a good structure I could use to implement this? I've looked at a few tutorials but haven't found a good modular way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. What is `currentControls`, what is `typeOfObj`, what are you trying to achieve with this line of code?

Comment: What controls do you use to "select an object on the board"?  Here are some [Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/index.html) I found with a Google search.

Comment: @Sergey, Im checking the object that has been selected by the player using the default controls as to change to the controls designated for that object. Hope that is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer on my own.

When creating my Controls Class I needed to over write the constructor to contain the object the Player had selected and update in the main game loop which object is currently selected. On instantiation of Controls the Keyboard, mouse, and game controller would be set the same way via the passed selectedObj The Keyboard class would then in turn would only do methods appropriate to the Obj:

if Dog is selected { A: left, D: right}

if bird is selected {A: fly left, D: fly right}